# Update database only by pressing link

Tags: php, html, prepared-statement

I have this code with some images, like this:

```
<img src="../images/woods/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this), add_items_oak(this), add_skills_oak(this)" class="a" name="oak"/>
<img src="../images/woods/oak.png" onclick="loadXMLDoc(this), add_items_oak(this), add_skills_oak(this)" class="b" name="oak" />
```

When one of them is pressed, an ajax call is run:

```
function loadXMLDoc(h)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var getEle = document.getElementsByClassName('woods1')[0];
        var imagePath ="../images/woods/oak_cut.png";
            h.src = imagePath + xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../database/update.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Which then updates the database by the use of this file:

```
<?php
        require('../includes/db_connect.php');

            /* Register a prepared statement */
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('      

            UPDATE items_woods t1 JOIN skills_woodcutting t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id
           SET t1.oak = oak+1,
               t2.exp = exp+13
         WHERE t1.id = ?;

            ')) {
                /* Bind parametres */
                $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

                /* Insert the parameter values */
                $id = 1;

                /* Execute the query */
                $stmt->execute();

                /* Close statement */
                $stmt->close();

            } else {
                /* Something went wrong */
                echo 'Something went terrible wrong' . $mysqli->error;
            }
?>
```

The problem now is that people can use the url to simulate a click on one of the images. Like writing something like: www.examplepage.com/database/update.php

I need `update.php` to check wether or not a image is clicked on.

I tried some code by having a value in the `<img>` tag that was set to true, and only if that was true at `update.php`, it would execute the code. This didn't help and since I am trying to find a solution that can't be cheated with, I thought about asking here. Any suggestions or advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the POST request

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // … your database code 
}
```

This would at least stop the update happening if the user simply visited the URL because that would constitute a GET request

Comment: Thanks! By the use of this, and the answer from Collin Grady, I can succeed in making a very secure tree-image :)

Comment: However do note that it is trivial for someone who really wants to cheat to fake a post. You can load jquery into a page and just `$.post("someurl")`

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not possible through any sort of standard method. There is no way to require someone to click a link vs visiting a URL directly.

You will have to do something like generating a one-time hash that only works for a short period of time, and only allow the script to work if that was passed in the link.

So if a user clicks a link with that hash, it'll work once, but future clicks with that same hash won't. They'd have to find the image again and click it a second time with a new hash to trigger the same function.

edit:

If you're doing what it looks like and making a sort of browser game where users see resources and click to claim them, could you generate a map first, and send the x/y coords they're clicking on, and then track that the resource was deleted?

Then if they try to "cut" the same x/y coord again, it wouldn't work since they already harvested it.

Comment: oh smart, would I store these hashes in the database?

Comment: Check my update; I didn't notice what it looked like before, so I added an alternate idea :)

Comment: I like both of the ideas, but I think the second idea is a bit too complex for me, I would rather create the hash and check if it's a "legal" click. That sounds nice

Comment: In that case, I would generate the hashes whenever you add a new tree to show the user; save it in the db somewhere, and if they click, you mark it as cut or just delete the hash entry (if you choose to delete, then make sure you validate that the hash is in the db on click before deleting; don't just issue a blind delete)

Comment: You could also include a timestamp on the hashes and prune the table of hashes older than a day or such, to handle people seeing them but never clicking them.